# Webview Android

Tags: android, webview

(Não sou programador, estou aprendendo) Problema: Tenho um site (tipo cms ) que faz upload de imagem. Aí pra facilitar aos meus usuarios, criei um Android(apk)-WebView que imprime na tela do celular a visão responsiva do meu site. Meus usuarios conseguem logar-se, enviar forms de texto, comentar postagens... a única coisa que não esta funcionando é upload de imagens(clico no botão e nada acontece). Por gentileza, Alguem consegue me instruir em como resolver isso?

Comment: E o código, fica difícil pra galera te ajudar sem ver nada, concorda?

Comment: Estou com o codigo mas n sei como compartilhar.